# Why doesn't linking a function of the wrong type return garbage?

Tags: c, gcc

I'm going through the K&R C book and chapter 4.2 says the following:

> If atof itself and the call to it in main have inconsistent types in the same source file, the error will be detected by the compiler. But if (as is more likely) atof were compiled separately, the mismatch would not be detected, atof would return a double that main would treat as an int, and meaningless answers would result.

I wanted to see for myself what would happen if I created and inconsistently used a function as they describe:

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int floatFunction();

int main() {
    int result = floatFunction();
    printf("result: %d\n", result);
}
```

floatFunction.c:

```
float floatFunction() {
    return 10;
}
```

bash:

```
$ gcc main.c floatFunction.c -o main
$ ./main
result: 0
$
```

Regardless of what value I had `floatFunction` return, I always got `0` as a result. I also tried compiling with `-o3`, same result. I was expecting to see the bit pattern of `10.0` interpreted as an int as a result. Why is this not happening?

Also, why doesn't the compilation process notify me that the types don't match and how can I protect myself from making a mistake like this in real code?

Comment: you have to declare float floatFunction() that is from separate compilation unit in your hello.c before you can use it.

Comment: compiler sees only for one translation unit at a time, it can check inconsistencies for type mismatch within single file. check out this for linker: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072459/why-doesnt-the-g-linker-warn-about-this-inconsistent-function-declaration

Comment: You should have looked at the disassembly to see what was going on.

Comment: And K&R cant possibly know what each compiler or language version is going to do as that is a big moving target. Then there is the ISA on top of that which is, no doubt, causing your confusion.

Comment: They did put the right language in there to cover what happened.  And you did get a meaningless answer.

Comment: To answer the title question: A `0` **is** garbage here.

Comment: Nowadays, when your program start, your registers, stack, heap and other memories are initalized with zeroes (or some special value for registers, such as 0xdeadbeef), so you cannot expect (pseudo)random values.

Answer (score 2):

There are different registers used for passing (and returning) floating-point vs. integral values (pointers and integers) on x86 at least.

Why you consistently had integral zero in the return-register for integral values, while the return-register for floating-point values was used for the true return-value, I don't know. Just luck probably.

See for example [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls (and user-space functions) on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-and-user-space-f) for more about Linux calling conventions.

Anyway, remember that whatever you observe, at least on the language level it is simply undefined behavior, anything goes.

Comment: "Just luck probably." -- _probably_ not.

Comment: Maybe not luck, but there is no reason in the calling convention for the zero afaics.

Comment: different registers if using hard float, which is what you are generally going to get on an x86 tool unless you do some work.  If soft float then possible/probable that you could change the return value and see something different from main()

Answer (score 2):

> I was expecting to see the bit pattern of 10.0 interpreted as an int as a result. Why is this not happening?

The most likely reason is that on your platform (which you didn't specify) floating point values are returned in a different register from the one in which integer values are returned.

For example, on `x86_64` the integer result is returned in the `rax` register, while double and float result is returned in the `xmm0` register.

Here is an [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) on various `x86` calling conventions.

If you are not on `x86_64`, you'll need to look up the calling conventions for your platform.

> Also, why doesn't the compilation process notify me that the types don't match

The compilation process only sees one source file (compilation unit) at at time, so it can't warn you.

The linker could, but only the AIX linker actually does (of the ones I know).

> how can I protect myself from making a mistake like this in real code?

By declaring your functions in a header file and including that header in both compilation units.